# why errors, Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::list()

Tags: php, laravel

why edit process fails, how to display the data in the dropdown ?

controller :

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data['data_article'] = Article::find($id);
    $data['tambah_author'] = \DB::table('authors')->list('username','id');
    $data['id_author'] = \DB::table('authors')->list('id');
    return View::make('article.edit',$data)->with('authors',$data);
}
```

VIew :

```
{{ Form::select('author',
                (['0' => 'Pilih Author'] + $tambah_author),
                $id_author,
                ['class'=>'form-control']) }}
```

thanks, for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to [Query Builder API](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_lists), you need to change `list` to `lists`:

`$data['tambah_author'] = \DB::table('authors')->lists('username','id');
$data['id_author'] = \DB::table('authors')->lists('id');`

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is `lists`.

So change to:

```
$data['tambah_author'] = \DB::table('authors')->lists('username','id');
$data['id_author'] = \DB::table('authors')->lists('id');
```